# Where can I fine information about creating user accounts for my app?

Tags: android

I'm a Java programmer for android and I create an app and wanna know how can I make a registering for my users who will use my app? I need to use them and that staff. and also How can I make the thing which I can use to manage the app and the users after the app would be finished. I was looking for that in google, but I just don't know what to search.

Comment: If you don't know what to search how can you suppose to get the answer? For registration you may use back end services as Parse.com or Google Cloud. Or your own server side.

Answer (score 0):

Use parse.com for backend and try to use options like sign in with facebook or google, they are convenient for the user.
Also google, you will learn a lot :)